# Associate UDF to existing Excel object

Tags: excel, vba, methods, user-defined-functions

I would like to write a UDF 'getAddress()' which basically returns the address of a range and I would like to append the function to the object 'Range' so that intellisense includes getAddress function to Range's method list.

Below the desired behaviour

`Range("A1"). *Intellisense list includes getAddress*`

`Range("A1").getAddress`

*Result*

`"A1"`

Is there a viable way to do this?

Comment: `Range("A1").Address`? This looks like and XY problem to me. UDFs are meant to be used in cells like formulas, not as part of VBA code. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to extend the built-in objects like `Range`. Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590434/modify-an-existing-vba-class